# how to use dotnet restore in tfs 2017 with corporate proxy

Tags: tfs, proxy, nuget

I can run the command below fine in my cmd:

C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe restore C:/TFSBuildAgent/_work/1/s/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.sln

But when run in tfs I get:

```
******************************************************************************
Starting: Build
******************************************************************************
Current agent version: '2.112.0'
Agent is running behind proxy server: 'http://correctProxyAddress:correctPort'
******************************************************************************
Starting: Get Sources
******************************************************************************
Prepending Path environment variable with directory containing 'tf.exe'.
Querying workspace information.
tf vc get /version:6 /recursive /overwrite C:\TFSBuildAgent\_work\1\s /loginType:OAuth /login:.,******** /noprompt
All files are up to date.
******************************************************************************
Finishing: Get Sources
******************************************************************************
******************************************************************************
Starting: Run dotnet
******************************************************************************
==============================================================================
Task         : Command Line
Description  : Run a command line with arguments
Version      : 1.1.2
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613735)
==============================================================================
dotnet --info
.NET Command Line Tools (2.0.0)
Product Information:
 Version:            2.0.0
 Commit SHA-1 hash:  cdcd1928c9
Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.15063
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.0\
Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host
  Version  : 2.0.0
  Build    : e8b8861ac7faf042c87a5c2f9f2d04c98b69f28d
******************************************************************************
Finishing: Run dotnet
******************************************************************************
******************************************************************************
Starting: dotnet restore
******************************************************************************
==============================================================================
Task         : .NET Core (PREVIEW)
Description  : Build, test and publish using dotnet core command-line.
Version      : 0.3.1
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=832194)
==============================================================================
C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe restore C:/TFSBuildAgent/_work/1/s/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.sln
  Restoring packages for C:\TFSBuildAgent\_work\1\s\HelloWorld\HelloWorld.Test\HelloWorld.Test.csproj...
  Restore completed in 12.37 ms for C:\TFSBuildAgent\_work\1\s\HelloWorld\HelloWorld\HelloWorld.csproj.
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.0\NuGet.targets(102,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. [C:\TFSBuildAgent\_work\1\s\HelloWorld\HelloWorld.sln]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.0\NuGet.targets(102,5): error :   An error occurred while sending the request. [C:\TFSBuildAgent\_work\1\s\HelloWorld\HelloWorld.sln]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.0\NuGet.targets(102,5): error :   The operation timed out [C:\TFSBuildAgent\_work\1\s\HelloWorld\HelloWorld.sln]
```

I have added the proxy settings to TFS's web.config in IIS, Nuget.config's with the proxy settings in both projects being built in this solution for good measure, editted the nuget config in

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 15.0\Tools
```

too which i think is the one it uses!

Nuget configs:

```
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="http_proxy" value="http://correctAddress:correctPort" />
    <add key="https_proxy" value="http://correctAddress:correctPort" />
  </config>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 15.0\Tools`　this path is TFS Sever installed path. Actually I could not find the `nuget.config` file in my TFS installed path under the same path. There is only a `Nuget.exe` command.

Besides the build is running on the build agent and use the agent server environment include nuget setting. When you queue the build, if you have not specify the `nuget.exe` path, TFS will auto use the default path in the agent folder such as ...agent\Worker\Tools\Nuget.exe

[image]

To change the corresponding `nuget.config` file on the build agent, you could try to change the file under appdata `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.config`   xxx stands for your **build service account**.